# Unable to Execute Motion Plan in MoveIt 2 and ROS2: Controller Manager Keeps Dying

Tags: simulation, robotics, ros2, moveit, motion-planning

**Hello Stack Overflow community,**

I am currently working on a project involving MoveIt 2 and ROS2 (Humble) where I am running a simulation of a six-jointed robot. I have successfully created a motion plan for my robot using MoveIt 2, but when I attempt to execute the plan, nothing occurs. Additionally, my controller manager repeatedly fails, which is a problem I have yet to solve.

I checked all config files and tried to add some changes also tried to solve the problem with GPT-4, but nothing worked.** IT'S VERY IMPORTANT FOR ME TO COMPLETE THIS PROJECT. IT'S MY COLLEGE PROJECT, AND I NEED TO COMPLETE IT SOON. PLEASE, ANYBODY HELP ME. I CAN GIVE ANY OTHER DETAILS YOU WANT.
**

Here is the log I received:

```
roskuttan@SILENT-KILLERED:~/hexa_bot_ws$ ros2 launch hexa_bot_description_moveit_config demo.launch.py use_sim_time:=true
[INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below /home/roskuttan/.ros/log/2023-05-31-21-33-40-784795-SILENT-KILLERED-11858
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
Using load_yaml() directly is deprecated. Use xacro.load_yaml() instead.
[INFO] [static_transform_publisher-1]: process started with pid [11859]
[INFO] [robot_state_publisher-2]: process started with pid [11861]
[INFO] [move_group-3]: process started with pid [11863]
[INFO] [rviz2-4]: process started with pid [11865]
[INFO] [ros2_control_node-5]: process started with pid [11867]
[INFO] [spawner-6]: process started with pid [11869]
[INFO] [spawner-7]: process started with pid [11871]
[static_transform_publisher-1] [INFO] [1685549021.419656555] [static_transform_publisher0]: Spinning until stopped - publishing transform
[static_transform_publisher-1] translation: ('0.000000', '0.000000', '0.000000')
[static_transform_publisher-1] rotation: ('0.000000', '0.000000', '0.000000', '1.000000')
[static_transform_publisher-1] from 'world' to 'base_link'
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1685549021.428105055] [resource_manager]: Loading hardware 'GazeboSystem'
[ros2_control_node-5] terminate called after throwing an instance of 'pluginlib::LibraryLoadException'
[ros2_control_node-5]   what():  According to the loaded plugin descriptions the class gazebo_ros2_control/GazeboSystem with base class type hardware_interface::SystemInterface does not exist. Declared types are  fake_components/GenericSystem mock_components/GenericSystem test_hardware_components/TestSystemCommandModes test_hardware_components/TestTwoJointSystem test_system
[ros2_control_node-5] Stack trace (most recent call last):
[ros2_control_node-5] #16   Object "", at 0xffffffffffffffff, in
[ros2_control_node-5] #15   Object "/opt/ros/humble/lib/controller_manager/ros2_control_node", at 0x55bfce760d84, in
[ros2_control_node-5] #14   Object "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", at 0x7f99cabb9e3f, in __libc_start_main
[robot_state_publisher-2] [WARN] [1685549021.429758155] [kdl_parser]: The root link base_link has an inertia specified in the URDF, but KDL does not support a root link with an inertia.  As a workaround, you can add an extra dummy link to your URDF.
[ros2_control_node-5] #13   Object "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", at 0x7f99cabb9d8f, in
[ros2_control_node-5] #12   Object "/opt/ros/humble/lib/controller_manager/ros2_control_node", at 0x55bfce76089e, in
[ros2_control_node-5] #11   Object "/opt/ros/humble/lib/libcontroller_manager.so", at 0x7f99cb26d171, in controller_manager::ControllerManager::ControllerManager(std::shared_ptr<rclcpp::Executor>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, rclcpp::NodeOptions const&)
[ros2_control_node-5] #10   Object "/opt/ros/humble/lib/libcontroller_manager.so", at 0x7f99cb26c257, in controller_manager::ControllerManager::init_resource_manager(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)
[robot_state_publisher-2] [INFO] [1685549021.429863355] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment JAW1_1
[robot_state_publisher-2] [INFO] [1685549021.429918055] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment JAW2_1
[robot_state_publisher-2] [INFO] [1685549021.429927655] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment JAW3_1
[robot_state_publisher-2] [INFO] [1685549021.429934355] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment JAW6_1
[robot_state_publisher-2] [INFO] [1685549021.429940655] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment Jaw4_1
[robot_state_publisher-2] [INFO] [1685549021.429946955] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment Jaw5_1
[robot_state_publisher-2] [INFO] [1685549021.429953255] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment NEMA_3_1
[robot_state_publisher-2] [INFO] [1685549021.429959555] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment NEMA_4_1
[robot_state_publisher-2] [INFO] [1685549021.429965955] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment NEMA_5_1
[robot_state_publisher-2] [INFO] [1685549021.429972355] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment Nema_1_1
[robot_state_publisher-2] [INFO] [1685549021.429978655] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment Nema_2_1
[robot_state_publisher-2] [INFO] [1685549021.429984755] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment Nema_6_1
[robot_state_publisher-2] [INFO] [1685549021.429991155] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment base_link
[ros2_control_node-5] #9    Object "/opt/ros/humble/lib/libhardware_interface.so", at 0x7f99caabe207, in hardware_interface::ResourceManager::load_urdf(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, bool)
[ros2_control_node-5] #8    Object "/opt/ros/humble/lib/libhardware_interface.so", at 0x7f99caac6856, in
[ros2_control_node-5] #7    Object "/opt/ros/humble/lib/libhardware_interface.so", at 0x7f99caa9d858, in
[ros2_control_node-5] #6    Object "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.30", at 0x7f99cae86517, in __cxa_throw
[ros2_control_node-5] #5    Object "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.30", at 0x7f99cae862b6, in std::terminate()
[ros2_control_node-5] #4    Object "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.30", at 0x7f99cae8624b, in
[ros2_control_node-5] #3    Object "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.30", at 0x7f99cae7abbd, in
[ros2_control_node-5] #2    Object "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", at 0x7f99cabb87f2, in abort
[ros2_control_node-5] #1    Object "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", at 0x7f99cabd2475, in raise
[ros2_control_node-5] #0    Object "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", at 0x7f99cac26a7c, in pthread_kill
[ros2_control_node-5] Aborted (Signal sent by tkill() 11867 1000)
[ERROR] [ros2_control_node-5]: process has died [pid 11867, exit code -6, cmd '/opt/ros/humble/lib/controller_manager/ros2_control_node --ros-args --params-file /tmp/launch_params_7r7rh_1h --params-file /home/roskuttan/hexa_bot_ws/install/hexa_bot_description_moveit_config/share/hexa_bot_description_moveit_config/config/ros2_controllers.yaml'].
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1685549021.449993556] [moveit_rdf_loader.rdf_loader]: Loaded robot model in 0.0034793 seconds
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1685549021.450093856] [moveit_robot_model.robot_model]: Loading robot model 'hexa_bot'...
[move_group-3] [WARN] [1685549021.554605257] [kdl_parser]: The root link base_link has an inertia specified in the URDF, but KDL does not support a root link with an inertia.  As a workaround, you can add an extra dummy link to your URDF.
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1685549021.826553560] [moveit_ros.planning_scene_monitor.planning_scene_monitor]: Publishing maintained planning scene on 'monitored_planning_scene'
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1685549021.826699960] [moveit.ros_planning_interface.moveit_cpp]: Listening to 'joint_states' for joint states
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1685549021.827212460] [moveit_ros.current_state_monitor]: Listening to joint states on topic 'joint_states'
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1685549021.827698260] [moveit_ros.planning_scene_monitor.planning_scene_monitor]: Listening to '/attached_collision_object' for attached collision objects
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1685549021.827730360] [moveit_ros.planning_scene_monitor.planning_scene_monitor]: Starting planning scene monitor
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1685549021.828636760] [moveit_ros.planning_scene_monitor.planning_scene_monitor]: Listening to '/planning_scene'
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1685549021.828666160] [moveit_ros.planning_scene_monitor.planning_scene_monitor]: Starting world geometry update monitor for collision objects, attached objects, octomap updates.
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1685549021.829195760] [moveit_ros.planning_scene_monitor.planning_scene_monitor]: Listening to 'collision_object'
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1685549021.829711260] [moveit_ros.planning_scene_monitor.planning_scene_monitor]: Listening to 'planning_scene_world' for planning scene world geometry
[move_group-3] [WARN] [1685549021.829869660] [moveit.ros.occupancy_map_monitor.middleware_handle]: Resolution not specified for Octomap. Assuming resolution = 0.1 instead
[move_group-3] [ERROR] [1685549021.829882660] [moveit.ros.occupancy_map_monitor.middleware_handle]: No 3D sensor plugin(s) defined for octomap updates
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1685549021.956556861] [moveit.ros_planning_interface.moveit_cpp]: Loading planning pipeline 'ompl'
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1685549021.967400661] [moveit.ros_planning.planning_pipeline]: Using planning interface 'OMPL'
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1685549021.968736261] [moveit_ros.add_time_optimal_parameterization]: Param 'ompl.path_tolerance' was not set. Using default value: 0.100000
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1685549021.968770861] [moveit_ros.add_time_optimal_parameterization]: Param 'ompl.resample_dt' was not set. Using default value: 0.100000
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1685549021.968776561] [moveit_ros.add_time_optimal_parameterization]: Param 'ompl.min_angle_change' was not set. Using default value: 0.001000
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1685549021.968795761] [moveit_ros.fix_workspace_bounds]: Param 'ompl.default_workspace_bounds' was not set. Using default value: 10.000000
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1685549021.968810061] [moveit_ros.fix_start_state_bounds]: Param 'ompl.start_state_max_bounds_error' was set to 0.100000
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1685549021.968814261] [moveit_ros.fix_start_state_bounds]: Param 'ompl.start_state_max_dt' was not set. Using default value: 0.500000
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1685549021.968823561] [moveit_ros.fix_start_state_collision]: Param 'ompl.start_state_max_dt' was not set. Using default value: 0.500000
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1685549021.968827461] [moveit_ros.fix_start_state_collision]: Param 'ompl.jiggle_fraction' was not set. Using default value: 0.020000
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1685549021.968831861] [moveit_ros.fix_start_state_collision]: Param 'ompl.max_sampling_attempts' was not set. Using default value: 100
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1685549021.968840961] [moveit.ros_planning.planning_pipeline]: Using planning request adapter 'Add Time Optimal Parameterization'
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1685549021.968843961] [moveit.ros_planning.planning_pipeline]: Using planning request adapter 'Resolve constraint frames to robot links'
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1685549021.968846661] [moveit.ros_planning.planning_pipeline]: Using planning request adapter 'Fix Workspace Bounds'
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1685549021.968849061] [moveit.ros_planning.planning_pipeline]: Using planning request adapter 'Fix Start State Bounds'
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1685549021.968851361] [moveit.ros_planning.planning_pipeline]: Using planning request adapter 'Fix Start State In Collision'
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1685549021.968870061] [moveit.ros_planning.planning_pipeline]: Using planning request adapter 'Fix Start State Path Constraints'
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1685549021.970424561] [moveit.ros_planning_interface.moveit_cpp]: Loading planning pipeline 'chomp'
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1685549021.971178561] [moveit.ros_planning.planning_pipeline]: Multiple planning plugins available. You should specify the '~planning_plugin' parameter. Using 'ompl_interface/OMPLPlanner' for now.
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1685549021.971303161] [moveit.ros_planning.planning_pipeline]: Using planning interface 'OMPL'
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1685549021.972436761] [moveit.ros_planning_interface.moveit_cpp]: Loading planning pipeline 'pilz_industrial_motion_planner'
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1685549021.974974061] [moveit.pilz_industrial_motion_planner.joint_limits_aggregator]: Reading limits from namespace robot_description_planning
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1685549021.985698861] [moveit.pilz_industrial_motion_planner]: Available plugins: pilz_industrial_motion_planner/PlanningContextLoaderCIRC pilz_industrial_motion_planner/PlanningContextLoaderLIN pilz_industrial_motion_planner/PlanningContextLoaderPTP
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1685549021.985751361] [moveit.pilz_industrial_motion_planner]: About to load: pilz_industrial_motion_planner/PlanningContextLoaderCIRC
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1685549021.986958761] [moveit.pilz_industrial_motion_planner]: Registered Algorithm [CIRC]
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1685549021.986990961] [moveit.pilz_industrial_motion_planner]: About to load: pilz_industrial_motion_planner/PlanningContextLoaderLIN
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1685549021.987695061] [moveit.pilz_industrial_motion_planner]: Registered Algorithm [LIN]
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1685549021.987727361] [moveit.pilz_industrial_motion_planner]: About to load: pilz_industrial_motion_planner/PlanningContextLoaderPTP
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1685549021.988397661] [moveit.pilz_industrial_motion_planner]: Registered Algorithm [PTP]
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1685549021.988430361] [moveit.ros_planning.planning_pipeline]: Using planning interface 'Pilz Industrial Motion Planner'
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1685549022.044199962] [moveit.plugins.moveit_simple_controller_manager]: Added FollowJointTrajectory controller for hexa_group_controller
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1685549022.044348862] [moveit.plugins.moveit_simple_controller_manager]: Returned 1 controllers in list
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1685549022.044368962] [moveit.plugins.moveit_simple_controller_manager]: Returned 1 controllers in list
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1685549022.044593362] [moveit_ros.trajectory_execution_manager]: Trajectory execution is managing controllers
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1685549022.044608362] [move_group.move_group]: MoveGroup debug mode is ON
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1685549022.062510262] [move_group.move_group]:
[move_group-3]
[move_group-3] ********************************************************
[move_group-3] * MoveGroup using:
[move_group-3] *     - ApplyPlanningSceneService
[move_group-3] *     - ClearOctomapService
[move_group-3] *     - CartesianPathService
[move_group-3] *     - ExecuteTrajectoryAction
[move_group-3] *     - GetPlanningSceneService
[move_group-3] *     - KinematicsService
[move_group-3] *     - MoveAction
[move_group-3] *     - MotionPlanService
[move_group-3] *     - QueryPlannersService
[move_group-3] *     - StateValidationService
[move_group-3] ********************************************************
[move_group-3]
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1685549022.062578162] [moveit_move_group_capabilities_base.move_group_context]: MoveGroup context using planning plugin ompl_interface/OMPLPlanner
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1685549022.062591762] [moveit_move_group_capabilities_base.move_group_context]: MoveGroup context initialization complete
[move_group-3] Loading 'move_group/ApplyPlanningSceneService'...
[move_group-3] Loading 'move_group/ClearOctomapService'...
[move_group-3] Loading 'move_group/MoveGroupCartesianPathService'...
[move_group-3] Loading 'move_group/MoveGroupExecuteTrajectoryAction'...
[move_group-3] Loading 'move_group/MoveGroupGetPlanningSceneService'...
[move_group-3] Loading 'move_group/MoveGroupKinematicsService'...
[move_group-3] Loading 'move_group/MoveGroupMoveAction'...
[move_group-3] Loading 'move_group/MoveGroupPlanService'...
[move_group-3] Loading 'move_group/MoveGroupQueryPlannersService'...
[move_group-3] Loading 'move_group/MoveGroupStateValidationService'...
[move_group-3]
[move_group-3] You can start planning now!
[move_group-3]
[rviz2-4] [INFO] [1685549023.470930477] [rviz2]: Stereo is NOT SUPPORTED
[rviz2-4] [INFO] [1685549023.471053777] [rviz2]: OpenGl version: 4.1 (GLSL 4.1)
[rviz2-4] [INFO] [1685549023.501633577] [rviz2]: Stereo is NOT SUPPORTED
[rviz2-4] Warning: class_loader.impl: SEVERE WARNING!!! A namespace collision has occurred with plugin factory for class rviz_default_plugins::displays::InteractiveMarkerDisplay. New factory will OVERWRITE existing one. This situation occurs when libraries containing plugins are directly linked against an executable (the one running right now generating this message). Please separate plugins out into their own library or just don't link against the library and use either class_loader::ClassLoader/MultiLibraryClassLoader to open.
[rviz2-4]          at line 253 in /opt/ros/humble/include/class_loader/class_loader/class_loader_core.hpp
[spawner-6] [INFO] [1685549023.684063179] [spawner_hexa_group_controller]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' node to exist
[spawner-7] [INFO] [1685549023.697945680] [spawner_joint_state_broadcaster]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' node to exist
[spawner-6] [INFO] [1685549025.692602801] [spawner_hexa_group_controller]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' node to exist
[spawner-7] [INFO] [1685549025.706280201] [spawner_joint_state_broadcaster]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' node to exist
[rviz2-4] [ERROR] [1685549026.603712111] [moveit_ros_visualization.motion_planning_frame]: Action server: /recognize_objects not available
[rviz2-4] [INFO] [1685549026.626118711] [moveit_ros_visualization.motion_planning_frame]: MoveGroup namespace changed: / -> . Reloading params.
[rviz2-4] [INFO] [1685549027.162018417] [moveit_rdf_loader.rdf_loader]: Loaded robot model in 0.419107 seconds
[rviz2-4] [INFO] [1685549027.162081317] [moveit_robot_model.robot_model]: Loading robot model 'hexa_bot'...
[rviz2-4] [WARN] [1685549027.265816918] [kdl_parser]: The root link base_link has an inertia specified in the URDF, but KDL does not support a root link with an inertia.  As a workaround, you can add an extra dummy link to your URDF.
[rviz2-4] [INFO] [1685549027.569002321] [moveit_ros.planning_scene_monitor.planning_scene_monitor]: Starting planning scene monitor
[rviz2-4] [INFO] [1685549027.570028021] [moveit_ros.planning_scene_monitor.planning_scene_monitor]: Listening to '/monitored_planning_scene'
[spawner-6] [INFO] [1685549027.701593522] [spawner_hexa_group_controller]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' node to exist
[spawner-7] [INFO] [1685549027.715603622] [spawner_joint_state_broadcaster]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' node to exist
[rviz2-4] [INFO] [1685549028.015328126] [interactive_marker_display_94082560574336]: Connected on namespace: /rviz_moveit_motion_planning_display/robot_interaction_interactive_marker_topic
[rviz2-4] [WARN] [1685549028.028109026] [kdl_parser]: The root link base_link has an inertia specified in the URDF, but KDL does not support a root link with an inertia.  As a workaround, you can add an extra dummy link to your URDF.
[rviz2-4] [INFO] [1685549028.037560326] [moveit_ros_visualization.motion_planning_frame]: group hexa_group
[rviz2-4] [INFO] [1685549028.037607926] [moveit_ros_visualization.motion_planning_frame]: Constructing new MoveGroup connection for group 'hexa_group' in namespace ''
[rviz2-4] [INFO] [1685549028.055481726] [move_group_interface]: Ready to take commands for planning group hexa_group.
[rviz2-4] [INFO] [1685549028.056432626] [moveit_ros_visualization.motion_planning_frame]: group hexa_group
[rviz2-4] [INFO] [1685549028.078346227] [interactive_marker_display_94082560574336]: Sending request for interactive markers
[rviz2-4] [INFO] [1685549028.110504727] [interactive_marker_display_94082560574336]: Service response received for initialization
[spawner-6] [INFO] [1685549029.709702566] [spawner_hexa_group_controller]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' node to exist
[spawner-7] [INFO] [1685549029.724280667] [spawner_joint_state_broadcaster]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' node to exist
[spawner-6] [ERROR] [1685549031.717070515] [spawner_hexa_group_controller]: Controller manager not available
[spawner-7] [ERROR] [1685549031.732596315] [spawner_joint_state_broadcaster]: Controller manager not available
[ERROR] [spawner-6]: process has died [pid 11869, exit code 1, cmd '/opt/ros/humble/lib/controller_manager/spawner hexa_group_controller --ros-args'].
[ERROR] [spawner-7]: process has died [pid 11871, exit code 1, cmd '/opt/ros/humble/lib/controller_manager/spawner joint_state_broadcaster --ros-args'].
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1685550203.588396713] [moveit_move_group_default_capabilities.move_action_capability]: Received request
[rviz2-4] [INFO] [1685550203.588840613] [move_group_interface]: Plan and Execute request accepted
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1685550203.589105613] [moveit_move_group_default_capabilities.move_action_capability]: executing..
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1685550204.589486014] [moveit_ros.current_state_monitor]: Didn't received robot state (joint angles) with recent timestamp within 1.000000 seconds.
[move_group-3] Check clock synchronization if your are running ROS across multiple machines!
[move_group-3] [WARN] [1685550204.589572414] [moveit_ros.planning_scene_monitor.planning_scene_monitor]: Failed to fetch current robot state.
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1685550204.589851214] [moveit_move_group_default_capabilities.move_action_capability]: Combined planning and execution request received for MoveGroup action. Forwarding to planning and execution pipeline.
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1685550204.590623014] [moveit_ros.plan_execution]: Planning attempt 1 of at most 1
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1685550204.590696614] [moveit_move_group_capabilities_base.move_group_capability]: Using planning pipeline 'ompl'
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1685550204.594164414] [moveit.ompl_planning.model_based_planning_context]: Planner configuration 'hexa_group' will use planner 'geometric::RRTConnect'. Additional configuration parameters will be set when the planner is constructed.
[move_group-3] [WARN] [1685550204.803294815] [moveit_trajectory_processing.time_optimal_trajectory_generation]: Joint velocity limits are not defined. Using the default 1 rad/s. You can define velocity limits in the URDF or joint_limits.yaml.
[move_group-3] [WARN] [1685550204.803342315] [moveit_trajectory_processing.time_optimal_trajectory_generation]: Joint acceleration limits are not defined. Using the default 1 rad/s^2. You can define acceleration limits in the URDF or joint_limits.yaml.
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1685550204.807110715] [moveit.plugins.moveit_simple_controller_manager]: Returned 1 controllers in list
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1685550204.807181715] [moveit.plugins.moveit_simple_controller_manager]: Returned 1 controllers in list
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1685550204.807390815] [moveit_ros.trajectory_execution_manager]: Validating trajectory with allowed_start_tolerance 0.01
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1685550205.807536415] [moveit_ros.current_state_monitor]: Didn't received robot state (joint angles) with recent timestamp within 1.000000 seconds.
[move_group-3] Check clock synchronization if your are running ROS across multiple machines!
[move_group-3] [WARN] [1685550205.807644115] [moveit_ros.trajectory_execution_manager]: Failed to validate trajectory: couldn't receive full current joint state within 1s
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1685550205.807974815] [moveit_move_group_default_capabilities.move_action_capability]: Solution found but controller failed during execution
[rviz2-4] [INFO] [1685550205.809449015] [move_group_interface]: Plan and Execute request aborted
[rviz2-4] [ERROR] [1685550205.889689215] [move_group_interface]: MoveGroupInterface::move() failed or timeout reached
[rviz2-4] [INFO] [1685550214.709188686] [move_group_interface]: MoveGroup action client/server ready
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1685550214.709703786] [moveit_move_group_default_capabilities.move_action_capability]: Received request
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1685550214.709881186] [moveit_move_group_default_capabilities.move_action_capability]: executing..
[rviz2-4] [INFO] [1685550214.709934386] [move_group_interface]: Planning request accepted
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1685550215.710077184] [moveit_ros.current_state_monitor]: Didn't received robot state (joint angles) with recent timestamp within 1.000000 seconds.
[move_group-3] Check clock synchronization if your are running ROS across multiple machines!
[move_group-3] [WARN] [1685550215.710154784] [moveit_ros.planning_scene_monitor.planning_scene_monitor]: Failed to fetch current robot state.
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1685550215.710255684] [moveit_move_group_default_capabilities.move_action_capability]: Planning request received for MoveGroup action. Forwarding to planning pipeline.
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1685550215.710386384] [moveit_move_group_capabilities_base.move_group_capability]: Using planning pipeline 'ompl'
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1685550215.710926284] [moveit.ompl_planning.model_based_planning_context]: Planner configuration 'hexa_group' will use planner 'geometric::RRTConnect'. Additional configuration parameters will be set when the planner is constructed.
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1685550215.919333384] [moveit_move_group_default_capabilities.move_action_capability]: Motion plan was computed successfully.
[rviz2-4] [INFO] [1685550215.919845184] [move_group_interface]: Planning request complete!
[rviz2-4] [INFO] [1685550216.010869384] [move_group_interface]: time taken to generate plan: 0.0359888 seconds
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1685550217.064185082] [moveit_move_group_default_capabilities.execute_trajectory_action_capability]: Received goal request
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1685550217.064419882] [moveit_move_group_default_capabilities.execute_trajectory_action_capability]: Execution request received
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1685550217.064451582] [moveit.plugins.moveit_simple_controller_manager]: Returned 1 controllers in list
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1685550217.064463882] [moveit.plugins.moveit_simple_controller_manager]: Returned 1 controllers in list
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1685550217.064563082] [moveit_ros.trajectory_execution_manager]: Validating trajectory with allowed_start_tolerance 0.01
[rviz2-4] [INFO] [1685550217.064417482] [move_group_interface]: Execute request accepted
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1685550218.064699880] [moveit_ros.current_state_monitor]: Didn't received robot state (joint angles) with recent timestamp within 1.000000 seconds.
[move_group-3] Check clock synchronization if your are running ROS across multiple machines!
[move_group-3] [WARN] [1685550218.064772280] [moveit_ros.trajectory_execution_manager]: Failed to validate trajectory: couldn't receive full current joint state within 1s
[move_group-3] [INFO] [1685550218.064894380] [moveit_move_group_default_capabilities.execute_trajectory_action_capability]: Execution completed: ABORTED
[rviz2-4] [INFO] [1685550218.065488680] [move_group_interface]: Execute request aborted
[rviz2-4] [ERROR] [1685550218.165020080] [move_group_interface]: MoveGroupInterface::execute() failed or timeout reached
```

RQT GRAPH:(https://i.stack.imgur.com/AUSss.jpg)]

Moveit2 Error:(https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZ2gD.png)

Answer (score 1):

Try to install gazebo_ros2_control and ros2_controller from source instead of binary:

https://github.com/ros-controls/gazebo_ros2_control/tree/humble
https://github.com/ros-controls/ros2_control/tree/humble